# tpm2-tools seal-unseal data after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, tpm

I'm trying to seal some data into the tpm2.0 and then later unseal it, even after the system reboots i should be able to unseal the data

In the transient memory of tpm, i can do this, this works

```
tpm2_pcrlist -L sha1:7 -o pcr.bin
tpm2_createpolicy -P -L sha1:7 -F pcr.bin -f policy.digest
tpm2_createprimary -H e -g sha256 -G rsa -C primary.context
tpm2_create -g sha256 -G keyedhash -u obj.pub -r obj.priv -c primary.context -L policy.digest -I- <<< "secret"
tpm2_load -c primary.context -u obj.pub -r obj.priv -n load.name -C load.context
tpm2_unseal -c load.context -L sha1:7
```

I'm able to unseal the data `secret`, but to make it usable I should be able to unseal it even after the system reboots, so for that I am making the SRK aka primary key a persistent object in tpm.

So far I have done this

```
tpm2_createpolicy -P -L sha1:7 -F pcr.bin -f policy.digest
tpm2_createprimary -H e -g sha256 -G rsa -C primary.context
tpm2_create -g sha256 -G keyedhash -u obj.pub -r obj.priv -c primary.context -L policy.digest -I- <<< "secret"
tpm2_load -c primary.context -u obj.pub -r obj.priv -n load.name -C load.context
tpm2_unseal -c load.context -L sha1:7

## persist the object into TPM's persistent memory
tpm2_evictcontrol -A o -c primary.context -H 0x81010001
```

## After Reboot

```
tpm2_load -H 0x81010001 -u obj.pub -r obj.priv -n load.name -C load.context
tpm2_unseal -c load.context -L sha1:7
```

I'm getting policy check failed error

```
error layer
  hex: 0x0
  identifier: TSS2_TPM_ERROR_LEVEL
  description: Error produced by the TPM
format 1 error code
  hex: 0x1d
  identifier: TPM_RC_POLICY_FAIL
  description: a policy check failed
```

Any idea how can I achieve it? i'm fairly new to TPM2.0

btw i'm using this version of tpm2-tools, running on ubuntu 16.04

```
root@server# apt-cache show tpm2-tools
Package: tpm2-tools
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Installed-Size: 1524
Maintainer: Mathieu Trudel-Lapierre <mathieu.trudel-lapierre@canonical.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3.1.3-2
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.22), libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2), libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0), libtss2-esys0
Description-en: TPM 2.0 utilities
 This package contains a set of tools to use with TPM 2.0 chips,
 for common tasks and features provided by the hardware; such as
 for doing basic key management, attestation, encryption and signing.
Description-md5: 7dab290b7414623bbe70b4f8bc047903
Homepage: https://github.com/01org/tpm2.0-tools

Package: tpm2-tools
Priority: optional
Section: universe/utils
Installed-Size: 964
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.0.0+20160226.64b3334-0ubuntu2
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0), libtss2-0, libtss2-utils
Filename: pool/universe/t/tpm2-tools/tpm2-tools_1.0.0+20160226.64b3334-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
Size: 90006
MD5sum: 2a5dd741bab5ba886508b87559d1151d
SHA1: 65c4f508b8643d808eb28e481dc660a68a0aba3d
SHA256: a8127c59b2ac7520f8f8993e9849f9dcc46486bced2f4b54c7fef56ac8e3b59e
Description-en: TPM 2.0 utilities
 This package contains a set of tools to use with TPM 2.0 chips,
 for common tasks and features provided by the hardware; such as
 for doing basic key management, attestation, encryption and signing.
Description-md5: 7dab290b7414623bbe70b4f8bc047903
Homepage: https://github.com/01org/tpm2.0-tools
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

Comment: Did you check if tpm2_pcrlist gives the same result for sha1:7 before you create the policy and after the restart?

Comment: yes they were the same

Answer (score 0):

The primary object is transient.  I suggest that you try to re-create the primary object before the tpm2_load

```
  tpm2_createprimary -H e -g sha256 -G rsa -C primary.context
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is using `-c` in combination with `-H` instead of `-S` for `tpm2_evictcontrol` and you might want to evict the load.context instead of the primary one.

```
OPTIONS
    -A, --auth=AUTH: The authorization used to authorize the commands. Valid choices are:
        o for TPM_RH_OWNER
        p for TPM_RH_PLATFORM

    -H, --handle=HANDLE: The handle of a loaded transient or a persistent object.

    If the handle is for a transient object, then a handle that will be assigned to the persisted object must also be specified with the -S option.

    If the handle is for a persistent object, then the -S does not need to be provided since the handle must be the same for both options.

    -c, --context=OBJECT_CONTEXT_FILE: Filename for object context.

    -S, --persistent=PERSISTENT_HANDLE: The persistent handle for the object handle specified via HANDLE.

    -P, --pwda=AUTH_PASSWORD: authorization password, optional. Passwords should follow the "password formatting standards, see section "Password Formatting".
```

Source: https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/3.1.3/man/tpm2_evictcontrol.1.md

The syntax changed a lot since then, but you might need `--persistent` to select the target handle. More recent version of tpm2-tools will automatically select the first unused handle if not explicitly specified. You specify `--context` to select which transient object, which might conflict with `--handle` selecting by another reference.

Another issue might be the context you try to evict, because it is not the one you created with `tpm2_load` command. The most simple command would look like `tpm2_evictcontrol -c load.context` which defaults to owner hierarchy for authorization in more recent versions.

You can use `tpm2_listpersistant` to display defined persistent objects.

Please tell us if this or sth else solved your issue and consider upgrading to newer versions of the tpm2-tss and tools.

I'm curious where you picked up these instructions. Did you follow a public guideline? If so, please share a link. Reviewed guidelines for a more recent version are:
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/code-sample-protecting-secret-data-and-keys-using-intel-platform-trust-technology.html and
https://tpm2-software.github.io/2020/04/13/Disk-Encryption.html